# OOP returning somewhat unaccessable array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, pdo

Ok so I'm trying to return an array in a class file, and echo the array like array['variable']; but for some reason it's saying the variable inside the [] brackets is undefined, but when I var_dump the array, it displays the all of the arrays contents normally. Here's my code:

Login.class.php

```
<?php

    class login {

        public $database;
        public $username;
        public $password;

        function __construct($database, $username, $password) {
            $this->database = $database;
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->password = $password;
        }

        public function encrypt() {
            return md5(md5($this->password));
        }

        public function doLogin() {
                $IsVerified = $this->database->getRows("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ? AND `password` = ?", array($this->username, $this->encrypt()));
                return $IsVerified;
        }
    }
```

Here's the login.php

```
if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    include('functions/config.php');
    include('functions/login.class.php');

    $database = new config(array());

    $login_func = new login($database, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

    $UserData = $login_func->doLogin();

    echo $UserData['firstname'];
    //echo($UserData["email"]);
}
```

config.php

```
<?php

    class config
    {
        public $isConnected;
        protected $datab;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $dbname;
        public $host;

        public function __construct($options=array()){
            $this->username = "root";
            $this->password = "";
            $this->dbname = "";
            $this->host = "localhost";
            $this->isConnected = true;

            try { 
                $this->datab = new PDO("mysql:host={$this->host};dbname={$this->dbname};charset=utf8", $this->username, $this->password, $options); 
                $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
                $this->datab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            } 
            catch(PDOException $e) { 
                $this->isConnected = false;
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public function Disconnect(){
            $this->datab = null;
            $this->isConnected = false;
        }

        public function getRow($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->fetch();  
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public function getRows($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->fetchAll();       
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }       
        }

        public function getRowCount($query, $params=array()){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                return $stmt->rowCount();  
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        public function insertRow($query, $params){
            try{ 
                $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query); 
                $stmt->execute($params);
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
            }           
        }

        public function updateRow($query, $params){
            return $this->insertRow($query, $params);
        }

        public function deleteRow($query, $params){
            return $this->insertRow($query, $params);
        }
    }

?>
```

The part that is not working is in the login.php >>>

```
$database = new config(array());

$login_func = new login($database, $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

$UserData = $login_func->doLogin();

echo $UserData['firstname'];
```

When I try to echo $userdata['firstname']; it says 
"Notice: Undefined index: firstname in C:\xampp\htdocs\site\login.php on line 13"

But when I var_dump, it displays all of the arrayed contents.
Any help is much appreciated.

Here's the var_dump as requested

```
array(1) {
    [0]=> array(10) {
        ["id"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["username"]=> string(7) "patrick" 
        ["password"]=> string(32) "432g1hjkgj2hgjhg34342" 
        ["groupid"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["email"]=> string(15) "email@gmail.com" 
        ["verified"]=> string(1) "0" 
        ["birthday"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["firstname"]=> string(4) "john" 
        ["lastname"]=> string(9) "cena" 
        ["regdate"]=> string(0) "" 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Its likely an object, not an array. Try to access propertys like $userdata->firstname

Comment: Already tried, said it wasn't an object "Trying to get property of non-objec"

Comment: Can you add the `var_dump()`?

Comment: What you need to do to find the problem yourself, next time, is to 
var_export($UserData)
right before the echo.

That way you can clearly identify what is is that you're trying to access.  

If it's empty, try to go back and debug why is the data missing

Comment: All this work and using MD5 (*tsk tsk*). Use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

Answer (score 2):

A `var_dump()` would make this easier, but in your `doLogin()` method you are calling the `getRows()` method which in turn calls [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) on a PDO object.

So you would probably need:

```
$UserData[0]['firstname']
```

**Edit:** Just confirmed by the `var_dump()`...

Comment: I love when SO people beat eachother by seconds :-)

Comment: @ManuelArwedSchmidt Agreed. However, I'd say jeroen knew what the issue was before var_dump().

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should be $UserData[0]['firstname'] then. See [PHP Doc on PDO::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)